# Using button in table and passing data from a cell in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use javascript to retrieve the data from row.insertCell(0) unfortunately I don't believe I am setting up my this statement correctly so I am getting nothing back. I would appreciate some advice on this.

```js
var cardTable = document.getElementById("cardBody");


card.forEach(item => {
   let row          = cardTable.insertRow();
   let refNum       = row.insertCell(0);
   refNum.innerHTML = item.G1_Card_Ref;
    
   let select       = row.insertCell(1);
   var sBtn         = document.createElement('input');
   sBtn.type        = "button";
   sBtn.className   = "btn";
   sBtn.style.color = "blue";
   sBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'editCard('this')');
   sBtn.value       = "Select";
   select.appendChild(sBtn);
```

This is a temporary function I created to look at the data coming back from the table.

```js
function editCard(CardRefNo) {
  document.getElementById("ecForm").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: What is `card`? And why are you declaring `cardTable` twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the onclick listener like this

```js
sBtn.onclick = function() {
    // do stuff with sBtn here, this is the new editCard function
    console.log(sBtn)
    document.getElementById("ecForm").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not transferring the data from the cell I need.